# Perform several hypothesis test at the same time (r)

Tags: r, testing, lapply

Imagine I want to assess the normality of several variables from a given dataset using the Shapiro-Wilk test.

In the example data, I also want to group by species.

```
data(iris)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

iris %>% 
  select(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)%>%
  group_by(iris$Species)%>%
  lapply(. , shapiro.test)
```

This gives me the error:

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : is.numeric(x) is not TRUE
```

I guess this error happens because lapply is computing the three variables as objects to apply the test, instead of grouping by species, and since Species is not numeric, it´s unable to compute it.

Any help would be appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dplyr` functions to calculate here.

To apply `shapiro.test` to each of  `Sepal.Length` and `Sepal.Width`

```
library(dplyr)

iris %>% 
  select(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Species) %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise(across(.fns = ~list(shapiro.test(.)))) -> result
result
  
#  Species    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width
#  <fct>      <list>       <list>     
#1 setosa     <htest>      <htest>    
#2 versicolor <htest>      <htest>    
#3 virginica  <htest>      <htest>
```

To get the p-value you can do :

```
iris %>% 
  select(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Species) %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise(across(.fns = ~shapiro.test(.)$p.value)) -> result
result

#  Species    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width
#  <fct>             <dbl>       <dbl>
#1 setosa            0.460       0.272
#2 versicolor        0.465       0.338
#3 virginica         0.258       0.181
```